# Can I set the bonding through dhcp for two nics connected to the same Wireless AP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, network-adapter, bonding

I have two NICs :

1. **wlo1** a pci nic
2. **wlxc83a35c1e40e** a usb nic

I plugged and ran both of them, and I got this routing table :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlxc83a35c1e40e
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlxc83a35c1e40e
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
```

I would like to team the two nics so that I gain in bandwidth through the same Wirless AP.

Using ifenslave (even if it is said to be obsolete) I succeed to enslave both the nics to **bond0** (after loading the corresponding module with the configuration mode balance-rr)

is this possible by setting an ip address and route to **bond0** using dhclient and route add ?

Comment: You need to keep in mind that link aggregation generally doesn’t increase the maximum achievable transfer rate of a single TCP connection. It’s more of a load balancing thing.

Comment: well, in fact, this is right for mode balance-rr, but how about 
**802.3ad**. I intend to team the two nics with mode balance-rr and later 
802.3ad :)

Comment: Nope, still won’t do for a single connection (or conversation, as others call it). That’s because frames must not be out of order. [This presentation](http://www.ieee802.org/3/hssg/public/apr07/frazier_01_0407.pdf) explains some of it.

Comment: 802.3ad is Ethernet specific. Since WLAN (802.11) is not Ethernet (802.3), I don't think 802.3ad is going to work.

Comment: you mean there is no way to make two wireless network card team together  to increase bandwidth using **bonding** ?

Comment: Note that even if you could find a bonding / load balancing scheme that works, you'd need the AP to be a simultaneous dual-band AP, because if it was a single band-at-a-time AP, your two NICs wouldn't be able to send (or receive) simultaneously. (Well, maybe you could speed things up in the downlink direction with MU-MIMO, but you probably would have mentioned if you were doing MU-MIMO.)